# JQuery Expand and hide table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I manage to make table row expand and hide but when I add another row it's like all row collapsed together .

Your help really appreciate.

JS

```
$('#more').on('click',function(event){
  $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('.hidden-row').toggle();
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fido3993/u3urfqmm/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `nextAll()`, just use `next()`.

Also there should not be repeated ids in an HTML document, so replace all of the `more` ids with classes.

Refer to the JSFiddle for what the updated code should look like.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obsp2cbe/1/)

Comment: Hi wowsk, yeah that working too but when i want hide another row it doesnt show any effect.

Comment: ahh yeah because the id omg. thank you . you are my life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **[`nexAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** which selects all `.hidden-row` siblings next to it, To get the immediate next sibling use **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** instead. Also you are using same `id` for td, it should be unique so only get selected the first element. For group of elements use `class` always.

```js
$('.more').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).closest('tr').next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="more" href="#">section</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden-row">
    <td colspan="10">Hahaha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="more" href="#">more</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden-row">
    <td colspan="10">Hahaha</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah because the id. Thank you. Noted